# Calling out data from Sqlite database base on date

Tags: c#

My end result is that the data from the database will populate the datagridview .

For now, I had limited myself to only call out 31 data and no more then that.  I also have errors calling the data out like from the dates. But i can call out base on part number but I guess I had set the rows on the girdview to 31 that's why it only can call out 31 data

I tried google and change the format of the calling of dates but it is not working

```
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\trendchart.db");
        con.Open();
        int i = 0;
        SQLiteCommand Insert = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from d where dateandtime = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "' and Date= '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(0).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") , con);
        SQLiteDataReader dr1 = Insert.ExecuteReader();
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView2.Refresh();

        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView2.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Date";
        dataGridView2.Rows[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Day (D) / Night (N)";
        dataGridView2.Rows[2].HeaderCell.Value = "TOP(1)";
        dataGridView2.Rows[3].HeaderCell.Value = "TOP(2)";
        dataGridView2.Rows[4].HeaderCell.Value = "Bottom(1)";
        dataGridView2.Rows[5].HeaderCell.Value = "Bottom(2)";
        dataGridView2.Rows[6].HeaderCell.Value = "X-TOP";
        dataGridView2.Rows[7].HeaderCell.Value = "X-BOT";
        dataGridView2.Rows[8].HeaderCell.Value = "X-T/B";
        dataGridView2.Rows[9].HeaderCell.Value = "Range";
        dataGridView2.Rows[10].HeaderCell.Value = "Employee no";
        dataGridView2.Rows[11].HeaderCell.Value = "Date&time";
        for (int r = 0; r < 31; r++)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[2].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[3].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[4].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[5].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[6].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[7].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[8].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[9].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[10].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[11].Cells[r].Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular);
            dataGridView2.Rows[6].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView2.Rows[7].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView2.Rows[8].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView2.Rows[9].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView2.Rows[10].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView2.Rows[11].Cells[r].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            string f1 = dr1.GetString(0);
            string f2 = dr1.GetString(1);
            string f3 = dr1.GetString(2);
            string f4 = dr1.GetString(3);
            string f5 = dr1.GetString(4);
            string f6 = dr1.GetString(5);
            string f7 = dr1.GetString(6);
            string f8 = dr1.GetString(7);
            string f9 = dr1.GetString(8);
            string f10 = dr1.GetString(9);
            string f11 = dr1.GetString(10);
            string f12 = dr1.GetString(11);
            dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = f1;
            dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[i].Value = f2;
            dataGridView2.Rows[2].Cells[i].Value = f3;
            dataGridView2.Rows[3].Cells[i].Value = f4;
            dataGridView2.Rows[4].Cells[i].Value = f5;
            dataGridView2.Rows[5].Cells[i].Value = f6;
            dataGridView2.Rows[6].Cells[i].Value = f7;
            dataGridView2.Rows[7].Cells[i].Value = f8;
            dataGridView2.Rows[8].Cells[i].Value = f9;
            dataGridView2.Rows[9].Cells[i].Value = f10;
            dataGridView2.Rows[10].Cells[i].Value = f11;
            dataGridView2.Rows[11].Cells[i].Value = f12;
            i++;

        }
```

"code = Error (1), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007BF): SQL logic error
unrecognized token: "'29-12-2018""

[Datafrom my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpwE.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jf0.png)

Comment: `DateTime.AddDays(0)` does nothing.

Comment: If i put DateTime.AddDays(1) isnt it adding to one more date to the date i had selected on the date time picker

Comment: Your query looks to be missing a closing quote. VTC for typo.

Answer (score 0):

Missing end quote add it like this:

```
SQLiteCommand Insert = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from d where dateandtime = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "' and Date= '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "'" , con);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but now i tried but no data is being retrived

Comment: my date in database is 22/11/2018 2:46:54 PM